# What does it mean to be a show's "screech"?

Tags: character, reference

The *Drop the Mic* battle between Kunal Nayyar and Mayim Bialik has the following [line](https://youtu.be/pHcJ0L7tEyw?t=126) from Mayim Bialik:

> You're basically our show's Screech.

The battle between Ashton Kutcher and Sean Combs has a [similar line](https://youtu.be/6h8QgZF5Qu4?t=283) referring to Screech, so this seems to be a somewhat common reference.

I don't get it though. Looking online, it seems that it might be a reference to Samuel Powers from *Saved by the Bell*. Is this correct? What is the nature of the Samuel Powers' character that would explain the line?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Screech, as you pointed out, was a comic relief but somewhat annoying character from [*Saved By The Bell* (1989-92)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096694/). He was played by Dustin Diamond, an actor with a troubled history who would eventually be arrested for possession of a switchblade knife after stabbing someone in a bar. His career never really went anywhere, much like his character on *Saved By The Bell*.

As such, a "Screech" is someone who is basically an annoying loser.

Comment: I'm not sure about Screech, but the Steve Urkel character basically single-handedly saved Family Matters.

Comment: There are different levels of annoying. As best I recall, Screech wasn't necessarily deliberately annoying, or at least annoying in the same way. Urkel was generally annoying in an endearing way, and his character wound up having a number of redeeming qualities. The audience simply didn't wind up feeling the same way about Screech.

Comment: @stannius it's one thing to be annoying to the other characters on the show, quite another to be annoying to the audience.

Comment: Dang, that last sentence in your main paragraph is brutal :P  ...But certainly gets the point across.

Comment: Semi-related:  https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLRcB4n4CGcy_r21EedmNUOyVP_puToBfr

Comment: Curious where the actor's troubled history comes into this. Was that mention necessary?

Comment: Possibly so, since it tends to explain some of the tone that those involved with pop culture use when discussing his history and his character. Otherwise, no.